# How can I get a struct's function that updates a variable in another view also refresh that view when changed?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var subtract = MinusToObject()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text("The number is \(MyObservedObject.shared.theObservedObjectToPass)")
            Text("Minus")
                .onTapGesture {
                    subtract.subtractIt()
                }
            
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView()) {
                    Text("Push")
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Master"))
            }

            
        }
    }
}

class MyObservedObject: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = MyObservedObject()
    private init() { }
    
    @Published var theObservedObjectToPass = 6
}

struct MinusToObject {
    func subtractIt() {
        MyObservedObject.shared.theObservedObjectToPass -= 1
    }
}
```

When I hit the `Minus` to call the function of my `subtract` instance, I know the value changes because if I go to another View I can see the new value, but the current view doesn't update.

I think I have to put a property wrapper around `var subtract = MinusToObject()` (I've tried several pretty blindly) and I feel like I should put a `$` somewhere for a two-way binding, but I can't figure out quite where.

Answer (score 1):

The `MinusToObject` is redundant. Here is way (keeping MyObservedObject shared if you want)...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var vm = MyObservedObject.shared
    //@StateObject private var vm = MyObservedObject.shared     // << SwiftUI 2.0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text("The number is \(vm.theObservedObjectToPass)")
            Text("Minus")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.vm.theObservedObjectToPass -= 1
                }
            
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView()) {
                    Text("Push")
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Master"))
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does work, I'm really just using it as an example to figure out how to use a second struct's instance method in a View that updates the View.  Maybe it's the case one should never do that?